# Confused with Web Services vs Websites (REST, JAX-RS, Servlets, etc)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I'm trying to understand the difference between Web Services and Websites.

In college, I learned how to build a website up by writing servlets and JSPs. However, I want to build"websites" using methods that people are using right now.

But I'm confused with the term of Web Services / Websites.

I was reading on JAX-RS, and it seems that JAX-RS is used for web services, and then I figured out there's a server side and client side. Does it mean that this application was created to communicate with each other using HTTP? An example is chat room that communicates through HTTP port? Then does this have nothing to do with creating website?

Does this means that JAX-RS is not used for building websites?

I'm being confused over this topic already. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Website you have developed using JSP and Servlet can be categorized as a fully fledged web application where there is a backend (database, etc) and a UI front end for user interaction.

Webservices on the other hand are a set of services exposed through a set of URL or URI which doesn't necessarily have a UI front end for direct user interaction. More like an API.

For Example, Facebook can be considered as a dynamic website and Facebook Developer API which provides different services for third party (such as authentication, friends list, messages etc) can be considered as web service.

```
I was reading on JAX-RS, and it seems that JAX-RS is used for web services, and then I figured out there's a server side and client side
```

Yes JAX-RS is mostly used in web services and web services do have a client side. This client is mostly another application written to call the web service and rarely has user interaction.

```
Does this means that JAX-RS is not used for building websites?
```

No it is possible to use JAX-RS to build websites also. If you layer your web services using JAX-RS and then create web pages with Javascript or Flex or some other client to consume and produce for those JAX-RS web services then you can build a web site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Does people still use JSPs and Servlets for website creation?

Comment: It is possible to use but hard work is required. Many use frameworks like struts or Spring MVC which is written on top of Servlets, Filters to each programming.

Comment: I know how to create websites with JSP and servlets. But I wanted to use something that is more "modern" since I'm also looking for some people to work with. Me writing JSP and servlets doesn't seem to help this situation. I think I'll start with Spring MVC, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

JAX-RS is a specification for RESTful Web Services with Java.

A service provides certain operations(server side). A client consumes the operations of a service. So a website could be a client of a service.

A web site can be used to collect and send data to services as well as display the results.

For example you login to a website to purchase a flight. The website asks for date of departure, departure city/state, destination city/state. Once you enter this information the website collects this data and builds a request and invokes some service. In return the service responds with flights that meet your date and destination requirements. The site parses this information and displays this data for you to choose the desired flight.

The website provides a user experience suitable for the data retrieved/displayed.
The web service enables the passing of this data via a defined request/response.